# Jquery OnClick Event - can I cache the page so it doesn't load again and again

Tags: jquery, browser-cache

**< a id="aboutTab" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="about();" >About< /a>**

When we click on About link..it loads about.html in a div and here is the function

**function(about) {  $('#idx').load('about.html'); }**

I want it should cache or something so when I click on about us next time it shouldn't load that page again.

At present, it calls about.html every time I click that link.  Can I just load it once and if that link is already clicked it should get cache so next time it doesn't load again.

About.html is quite heavy page as it read data from xml. So, I want to load it only one time and use cache if user click on that link again.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Check out pjax: http://pjax.heroku.com/. Once PJAX is being loaded on your page, you can then do things like this (from the [readme](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)):

```
<div id="main"><!--content will be loaded here--></div>
<a href='/explore' data-pjax='#main'>Explore</a>

$('a[data-pjax]').pjax()
```

Comment: Did you init it on your links in keeping with the documentation? I've revised my answer to clarify.

Comment: < a id="aboutTab" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="about();" >About< /a> When we click on About link..it loads about.html in a div and here is the function $.get('about.html', function(data) { $('#idx').html(data); }); I want it should cache or something so when I click on about us next time it shouldnt load that page again.

Answer (score 1):

use [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$("#AboutUs").one("click", function() {
   $(this).load('about.html');
})
```

#### update

alternative method ( click on the **link having id** will load the html from about.html )

```
$("a#linkID").click(function (e) { 
      $("#AboutUs").load('about.html');
      $(this).unbind(e.eventType);
});
```

note:

see additional note on **[`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Comment: OP wants the link to keep working, just doesn't want to do the Ajax request more than once.

Comment: $("#AboutUs").one("click", function() {
   $(this).load('about.html');
})
I am doing same but its not working. Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {

    var cache = {},
        aboutUsEl = $('#AboutUs');

    var aboutUs = function () {
        if (cache['aboutus']) {
            aboutUsEl.html(cache['aboutus']);
        } else {
            $.get('about.html')
                .done(function(response) {
                    cache['aboutus'] = response;
                    aboutUsEl.html(response);
                });
        }

    };

    aboutUsEl.click(aboutUs);

})();
```

Comment: Wouldn't `var aboutUs = ...` need to be `window.aboutUs = ...`

Comment: Not if the event handler were put in this same scope, an assumption I made but wasn't clear on, but then again, it says the function is being called in the onclick event, and scope wasn't really part of the question.

Comment: Sure. I just wanted to be sure the scope issue was mentioned. (And I suspected, as has been confirmed by another comment, that the OP was using an inline `onclick="aboutUs()"`.)

Comment: Well, I haven't seen your HTML, but if you are using inline JS, you won't be able to use this as is. I'll update to show what it should look like without inline JS.